# Regex: How to multiline-capture lines together that start with an Asterisk

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

**What I am trying to do**

I have a string that looks like this:

```
foobar

* Level1-1
* Level1-2
** Level2-1
** Level2-2
*** Level3-1
*** Level3-2

foo
foo
foo
bar

* Level1-1
foo

bar

foo
bar

* Level1-1
** Level2-1

foo
bar
```

I would like to use Regex to capture the lines starting with an Asterisk together, so given the string above I get the following three results captured together:

Result 1

```
* Level1-1
* Level1-2
** Level2-1
** Level2-2
*** Level3-1
*** Level3-2
```

Result 2

```
* Level1-1
```

Result 3

```
* Level1-1
** Level2-1
```

**What I tried**

I tried to use this regex with a multiline flag (/m):

```
^(?<Content>\*(.|\n|\r|\n\r)+)(?=[\n\r]+[^\*]+)
```

The regex as is understand/intended it:

`^` = Line/String Start

`(?<Content>\*(.|\n|\r|\n\r)+)` = The Capture Group that multiline-matches all lines that start with an Asterisk

`(?=[\n\r]+[^\*]+)` = Positive Lookahead to match any line that does not start with/contain an Asterisk, thus ending the match.

I expected this regex to match what I need, but it actually matches the whole string apart from the first 2 lines and the last line of my string.

I know that I could easily match the single lines with the following regex `(^\*.*)`, but I need the subsequent lines containing Asterisks to go into a single group instead of one group for each line.

**The Question**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, especially with the positive lookahead part, and I would be very grateful for any advice on how I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially started trying to use multiline mode, but then gave up and fell back to a plain regex with no special modes:

```
(?<=^|\n)\*+.*(?:\n\*+.*)*
```

### Demo

Explanation:

- `(?<=^|\n)` assert that match begins with start of the line
- `\*+` match one or more stars
- `.*` match rest of the line
- `(?:`

  - `\n` match a newline
  - `\*+` match one or more stars
  - `.*` match the rest of the line
- `)*` zero or more times

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `^(?<Content>\*(.|\n|\r|\n\r)+)(?=[\n\r]+[^\*]+)` with the multiline flag matches too much because it is greedy.

You can make the pattern non greedy to get the desired matches:

```
^(?<Content>\*(?:.|\n|\r|\n\r)+?)(?=[\n\r]+[^\*]+)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/HLZFOH/1).

Which is shorted written as this:

```
^(?<Content>\*[\s\S]+?)(?=\r?\n[^*])
```

But note that both patterns need to match a newline followed by at least a single char other than an asterix due to this part `[^\*]`

If there does not have to be a newline, you could write it like this:

```
^(?<Content>\*.*(?:\r?\n\*.*)*)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/g5b6xg/1).